# RavenDB - Planning for scalability

Tags: scalability, sharding, ravendb

I have been learning RavenDB recently and would like to put it to use.

I was wondering what advice or suggestions people had around building the system in a way that is ready to scale, specifically sharding the data across servers, but that can start on a single server and only grow as needed.

Is it advisable, or even possible, to create multiple databases on a single instance and implement sharding across them. Then to scale it would simply be a matter of spreading these databases across the machines?

My first impression is that this approach would work, but I would be interested to hear the opinions and experiences of others.

Update 1:

I have been thinking more on this topic. I think my problem with the "sort it out later" approach is that it seems to me difficult to spread data evenly across servers in that situation. I will not have a string key which I can range on (A-E,F-M..) it will be done with numbers.

This leaves two options I can see. Either break it at boundaries, so 1-50000 is on shard 1, 50001-100000 is on shard 2, but then with a site that ages, say like this one, your original shards will be doing a lot less work. Alternatively a strategy that round robins the shards and put the shard id into the key will suffer if you need to move a document to a new shard, it would change the key and break urls that have used the key.

So my new idea, and again I am putting it out there for comment, would be to create from day one a bucketting system. Which works like stuffing the shard id into the key, but you start with a large number, say 1000 which you distribute evenly between. Then when it comes time to split the load into a shard, you can say move buckets 501-1000 to the new server and write your shard logic that 1-500 goes to shard 1 and 501-1000 goes to shard 2. Then when a third server comes online you pick another range of buckets and adjust.

To my eye this gives you the ability to split into as many shards as you originally created buckets, spreading the load evenly both in terms of quantity and age. Without having to change keys.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but really unnecessary. You can start using one instance, and then scale when necessary by setting up sharding later.

Also see:

http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-sharding

http://ayende.com/blog/4830/ravendb-auto-sharding-bundle-design-early-thoughts

http://ravendb.net/documentation/replication/sharding

Comment: Thanks for the auto-sharding link I had not seen that. I guess my trouble with "sorting it out later" is that I want a strategy that balances he data across servers, not one that fills up one server then moves on to the next. Which brings up the issue of moving documents between shards when new ones are added. So I am trying to plan for that in advance where possible.

Comment: I updated the question with my new thinking on this topic. What are your thoughts on this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need all that at this point. You can always add sharding later, and RavenDB will do the work for you.

Comment: You eventually need to tell it how to get from a key to a shard though right? At which point you either need to change your keys, breaking web links that used them, or shard based on key range leaving an uneven distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good solution is to use virtual shards. You can start with one server and point all virtual shard to a single server. Use module on the incremental id to evenly distribute the rows across the virtual shards. With Amazon RDS you have the option to turn a slave into a master, so before you change the sharding configuration (point more virtual shards to the new server), you should make a slave a master, then update your configuration file, and then delete all the records on the new master using modulu that doesn't comply with the shard range that you use for the new instance.

You also need to delete rows from the original server, but by now all the new data with IDs that are modulu based on the new virtual shard ranges will point to the new server. So you actually don't need to move the data, but take advantage of Amazon RDS server promotion feature.

You can then make replica off the original server. You create a unique ID as: Shard ID + Table Type ID + Incremental number. So when you query the database, you know to which shard to go and fetch the data from.

I don't know how it's possible to do it with RavenDB, but it can work pretty well with Amazon RDS, because Amazon already provide you with replication and server promotion feature.

I agree that their should be a solution that right from the start offer seamless sociability and not telling the developer to sort the problems out when those occur. Furthermore, I've find out that many NoSQL solution that evenly distribute data across shards need to work within a cluster with low latency. So you have to take that into consideration. I've tried using Couchbase with two different EC2 machines (not in a dedicated Amazon cluster) and data balancing was very very slow. That adds to the overall cost too.

I also want to add that what pinterest had done to solve their scalability issues, using 4096 virtual shards.

You should also need to look into paging issues with many NoSQL databases. With that approach you can page data quite easily, but maybe not in the most efficient way, because you might need to query several databases. Another problem is changing schema. Pinterest solved this by putting all the data in a JSON Blob in MySQL. When you want to add a new column, you create a new table with the new column data + key, and can use Index on that column. If you need to query the data, for example, by email, you can create another table with the emails + ID and put an index on the email column. Counters are another problem , I mean atomic counters. So it's better taking those counters out from the JSON and put them in a column so you can increment the counter value.

There are great solutions out there, but at the end of the day you find out that they can be very expensive. I preferred spending time on building my own sharding solution and prevent myself the headache later on. If you choose the other path, there are plenty of companies waiting for you to get into trouble and ask for quite a lot of money to solve your problems. Because at the moment that you need them, they know that you will pay everything to make your project work again. That's from my own experience, that's why I am breaking my head to build my own sharding solution using your approach, which also be much cheaper.

Another option is to use middleware solutions for MySQL like ScaleBase or DBshards. So you can continue working with MySQL, but at the time you need to scale, they have well proven solution. And the costs might be much lower then the alternative.

Another tip: when you create your config for shards, put a write_lock attribute that accepts false or true. So when it false, data won't be written to that shard, so when you fetch the list of shards for specific table type (ie. users), it will be written only to the other shards for that same type. This is also good for backup, so you can show a friendly error for visitors when you want to lock all the shard when backing up all the data to get a point-in-time snapshots of all the shards. Although I think you can send a global request for snapshoting all the databases with Amazon RDS and using point-in-time backup.

The thing is that most companies won't spend time working with a DIY sharding solution , they will prefer paying for ScaleBase. Those solution comes from single developers that can afford paying for a scalable solution from the start, but want to rest assured that when they reach to the point they need it, they have a solution. Just look at the prices out there and you can figure out that it will cost you A LOT. I will gladly share my code with you once I'm done. You are going with the best path in my opinion, it's all depends on your application logic. I model my database to be simple, no joins, not complicated aggregation queries  - this solves many of my problems. In the future you can use Map Reduce to solve those big data queries needs.